# No data on socket input stream even though there is data

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I have a problem with my Java socket and connection. It seems like my input stream does not read any data even though there is data on the stream. Here is an example on how we read data:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
final int SO_TIME = 2500;
socket.setSoTimeout(SO_TIME);
long readTime = 0;
boolean remoteSocketClosed = false;
            
//Read data while the Remote-Socket is opened and the timeout is OK
while (!remoteSocketClosed && readTime < 30000)
{
    try
    {
        int c = is.read();
                    
        if (c != -1)
        {           
            buf.append((char)c);
        }
        else //c==-1
        {
            remoteSocketClosed = true;
        }
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException socketTimeout)
    {
        readTime += SO_TIME;
    }
}
            
if (readTime >= 30000)
{
    throw new IOException("No answer from server after request (" + readTime +"ms )");
}
else
{
    if (buf.length() > 0)
    {                       
        return buf;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        if (socket!=null)
            socket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        l.error("Socket not closed", e);
    }
            
    try{Thread.sleep(250);}catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Now this looks fine to me. However when there is data on the stream, it will not get picked up. I can use telnet and see that data is coming in on that connection, yet Java just throws the IOException (timeout).

The server is running on the same machine (localhost), and we can send data to the server, yet the answer is lost somehow (only in Java not in telnet). Is this some weird setting I don't know about? We are using Windows 10 and Java 8, firewalls are all disabled. I have never experienced something like this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you sending data to the server? Did you flush it? Maybe your server is still waiting for data before sending a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just don't see the forest for the trees and have to sleep over it...

The problem is my condition

```
if (c != -1)
{           
    buf.append((char)c);
}
else //c==-1
{
    remoteSocketClosed = true;
}
```

But the server never closes the connection... So I never exit my loop and im stuck for 30 seconds running into socket timeouts. After the 30 seconds of waiting my answer is in the StringBuffer but of course my readTime is 30000 so I throw the exception rather providing an answer...  I will have to think of an EndOfPackage Byte or something to avoid this.
Thanks for any help tho